# Is passing object to method is more efficient than calling the method by object?

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner in java and I want to  have this clarification.Is passing objects in a method is more efficient than calling the method by a class instance?It looks to me the same.Suppose the following example code:

```
public class Test { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
       CircleWithPrivateDataFields myCircle = new CircleWithPrivateDataFields(5.0); 
       printCircle(myCircle);
   } 

   public static void  printCircle (CircleWithPrivateDataFields c) { 
       System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius " 
          + c.getRadius() + " is " + c.getArea()); 
   } 
}
```

If I define `CircleWithPrivateDataFields` class,this passing method to object`printCircle` method will print on the console.Also, usually when I use void method, I need to write inside main method `System.out.print(void method);` to print void method on the console but when I pass object in the method, I don't need to do that.

Comment: There is no applicable difference - worrying about such will just lead to poorly designed code. While the Java bytecode (and work done) needed to call a virtual method and a static method are slightly different, this should probably be approached as an implementation/academic question.

Comment: Your question is close to meaningless, since the term "efficient" does not really apply here. I would worry more about creating classes that make sense, that have single responsibility, that have low coupling and high cohesion.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but if I don't clarify such concerns, chances are I will never learn.As a beginner and an aspiring student, I think it's incumbent on me to learn, even if it sounds ridiculous to the adept programmers like you.One day i will be like you too ;)

Comment: @Zakir For some technical details (which are not required to write good code), see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1504633/2864740 and http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-bytecode-fundamentals-using-objects-and-calling-methods/ etc. (And this is without even considering the JIT.)

Comment: Why not simply give your CircleWithPrivateDataFields a decent `public String toString()` method override, and your problem's solved? Then you can simply pass an object of this class into a println method call and be good.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Just learned a new technique from you.Thanks and will remember.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for sharing the link, I will learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanest is to simply give the class a `toString()` method override, and then you can simply print it out since the `out(...)` method of the PrintStream class will call the `toString()` method of any object passed into it:

```
public class CircleWithPrivateDataFields {
    private double radius;

    public CircleWithPrivateDataFields(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("The area of the circle of radius %.2f is %.2f", radius, getArea());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircleWithPrivateDataFields circle = new CircleWithPrivateDataFields(5);
        System.out.println(circle);
    }

}
```

Note that efficiency has nothing to do with this.

Also note that `toString()` methods are great as debugging help and as output for toy programs as shown above, but are almost never used as output methods for production code.

Comment: Yes noted.Thanks I will remember.